A Mathematical Approach to Solving a Sudoku Puzzle
I've been trying to develop the most efficient algorithm to solve a Sudoku puzzle. The one that I've developed isn't able to solve certain kinds of puzzles without having to use backtracking. One such puzzle is given in Figure 4.1 and its corresponding solution is given in Figure 4.2. There are certain terms that are used and interpreted differently in the context of Sudoku; in this post, such terms must be interpreted according to the definitions listed in the table in Figure 1.1. The Sudoku under consideration in this post is the standard Sudoku, which consists of nine rows and nine columns, comprising a total of 81 cells. I have excluded the backtracking part from the algorithm given in this post since the point of posting this algorithm here is to show that it isn't able to solve certain kinds of puzzles without using backtracking.
The description of my algorithm is as follows:

Create an array named cells_to_be_checked.
Loop through all the empty cells. Perform the following sub-steps for each cell.

Write the notes that belong to that cell and add the cell to cells_to_be_checked.


Loop through all cells in cells_to_be_checked. Perform the following sub-steps for each cell.

Eliminate any notes that, if were to be written down as a permanent value to the cell, would cause a violation. (See Figure 2.1.)
If the cell has only one note, write the value of that note as a permanent value to that cell. Insert the cells from the same groups as the cell that was updated to cells_to_be_checked. (See Figure 2.2.)
If a note appears only once in a group, update the cell containing that note with the value of that note. Insert the cells from the same groups as the cell that was updated to cells_to_be_checked. (See Figure 2.3.)
If cells_to_be_checked isn't empty, go to Step 3. again.



Note:

After Steps 1 and 2, each cell in the grid should either have a permanent value or at least one note.
To see what cells are added to cells_to_be_checked after an update is made, see Figure 3.1.

Here are my questions:

While my algorithm isn't able to solve certain kinds of puzzles without having to resort to backtracking, I believe that it efficiently solves the puzzles that it is able to solve. However, I may be wrong since I currently do not possess the mathematical prowess to prove that. Can my algorithm be improved to make it significantly faster?
Since every valid puzzle corresponds to only one solution, is there any way to obtain a number (loosely speaking, it can be thought of as a fingerprint of a puzzle that is unique for every valid puzzle) that uniquely identifies a puzzle, and then plug that number into some formula that outputs a unique number that corresponds to the puzzle's solution?
If the answer to Question 2. is no, is there an efficient algorithm that is guaranteed to solve a puzzle without having to use backtracking?

As a CS student and maths enthusiast, I do not like backtracking because it is essentially a trial-and-error approach. I have a strong conviction that there must be an algorithm that is guaranteed to solve a valid puzzle by using the properties of a Sudoku grid without having to resort to backtracking. I would be glad to get any insights and also learn about things that although might not be relevant to the topic under consideration, but related to it in some way.
Here's the link to all the figures: https://imgur.com/a/TuxRPwC.
Edit(s):

In Figure 3.1, I should have highlighted the second row (R2) instead of the third row.


There is certainly mathematical content here, so the question is on-topic for Math.SE. However, I wonder if folks at Puzzling.SE might have worthwhile insights.

Your algorithm utilizes the hidden single and naked single strategies, but the higher-order strategies, like naked double, for example, can’t be done. Read this

See the ‘how to solve this puzzle’ for the sudoku here for many other strategies.

@Soham Saha Surely, those things are interesting and I'm definitely going to go through them, but I'm particularly interested in a method that guarantees a solution for any puzzle without having to use a trial-and-error approach.

Sudoku's can sometimes not be solved without backtracking (or alternatively approaches so complicated that backtracking is not more difficult). Even exotic tools do not always help.

In other words , some trial and error is in general inevitable.

The only thing that comes to my mind that does not immediately involve backtracking is constraint programming: especially assuming there is one and only one solution, that should be guaranteed to converge to it by just subsequently applying the consistency constraints to the variables' domains.
